# Angular Material - Change md-select focus border bottom and selected md-option color

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

By default angular material md-select changes the focused bottom border colour and selected md-option colour to purple, and I've tried changing these through css but can't find the right selectors.

Which selectors do I need to use to change these?

Answer (score 3):

To change border-bottom color after focus or selecting option use this

```
md-select:not([disabled]):focus .md-select-value{
  border-bottom-color: #000;
}
```

Use `!important` if necessary. Hope it will help.